# Post a list of objetcs and an int into a Core MVC Controller with jQuery Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to pass an array of objects AND an int into a Core MVC Controller with a jQuery Ajax post.

I have seen many and many answers for this problem but I didn't find one which works for me... It's seems that the use of the Core MVC don't work for this like a classic MVC.

Object class :

```
public class Field : Nameable //herit of the ID and Name properties
{
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public Field () { }
}
```

MVC Controller function :

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SaveFields(List<Field> fields, int id)
{
   return Json(new { success = true, responseText = "OK" });
}
```

jQuery function :

```
$('#btnSaveFields').click(function () {
    var $rows = $('#table').find('tr:not(:hidden)');
    var data = [];
    var id = 1;

    // Turn all existing rows into a loopable array
    $rows.each(function () {
        var $td = $(this).find('td');
        var obj = new Object();
        obj.ID = $td.eq(0).children().attr('value');
        obj.Name = $td.eq(0).text().trim();
        obj.Value= $td.eq(1).text();
        data.push(obj);
    });
    data.shift(); // don't take the headers row
    console.log(data[0]); //seems ok
    var fields = JSON.stringify({ 'fields': data });

    $.ajax({
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: '@Url.Action("SaveFields")',
        //traditional: true, //don't work or wrong use ?
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            'fields': fields,
            'id' : id
        },
        success: function (response) {
            console.log('ok')
        },
        error: {
            console.log('nok')
        }

    });
});
```

The call of the MVC controller function works but the parameters are null. Have you an idea on what i'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for my problem !

It was just a mistake in my typo. The 'C' of contentType must be in uppercase.

Answer :

```
$.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("SaveFields")',
        ContentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { fields: data, id: id },
        success: function (response) {
            console.log('OK')
        },
        error: function (){
            console.log('NOK');
        }

    });
```

Comment: Complete nonsense - read the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) - its `contentType` - lowercase `c`

Comment: I don't know why but it works. I didn't change anything else.

Comment: If you did that it means you are sending the data as the default `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'` which means the code you have shown in the question cannot possibly work